# Array que contiene objetos creados en JavaScript,¿Como mostrar el contenido del array en un div HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, array, objeto

El caso es que yo tengo esta funcion que me crea objetos de la clase Persona y me los guarda en un array.Me lo crea correctamente, el problema que tengo es que quiero mostrar el valor del objeto creado en un div HTML.
Este es el constructor de la clase Persona.

```
class Persona
    constructor(nombre,apellidos,direccion,salarioBruto,salarioNeto){
        this._nombre = nombre;
        this._apellidos = apellidos;
        this._direccion =  direccion;
        this._salarioBruto = salarioBruto;
        this._salarioNeto = salarioNeto;
    }

function crear(){
    var nombreI = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    var apellidoI = document.getElementById('apellidos').value;
    var direccionI = document.getElementById('direccion').value;

    var salarioBrutoI = document.getElementById('salarioBruto').value;
    var salarioNetoI = document.getElementById('salarioNeto').value;
    var bruto = document.getElementById('salarioBruto').value;
    var retencion = document.getElementById('retenciones').value;
    var neto = bruto*retencion/100;
    document.getElementById('salarioNeto').value = neto;

    personas[personas.length]=new Persona(nombreI,apellidoI,direccionI,salarioBrutoI,neto,retencion);
    console.log(personas);
}
```

Comment: Publica tambien el objeto `Persona` ya que esta en el ejemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
class Persona {
 constructor(n,e) {
 this.name = n; this.edad = e;
 }
}
var people1 = new Persona("Eduardo", 17),
    div = document.getElementById("getInfo");

for(var props in people1) {
  div.innerHTML += " " + people1[props];
}
```

```css
#getInfo {
background-color: pink;
border: 2px solid purple;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="getInfo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes escribir el objeto directamente en tu DIV como un string así:

```js
class Pelota {
  constructor(color, x, y) {
    this._color = color;
    this._x = x;
    this._y = y;
   }
}

const pelota = new Pelota('red', 10, 20);
document.querySelector('#div').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(pelota);
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```